# F# Is there a more effective or idiomatic way to reference a table of values

Tags: f#, nested-lists

If there was an unchanging tables of values that functions will need to look up from occasionally
, say a 4x5 table, where the columns are fruits and the rows are birds. And I want a function that given a fruit and a bird looks up the right value in the table.

Below is how I went about doing it, I'm wondering if there is a more idiomatic F# way? Or a simpler or more efficient way?

```
let getter bird fruit =
    let listoflists =
    [ "Eagle", [ "Cherry", 1.1; "Pear", 1.4; "Orange", 1.2; "Apple", 1.1; "Banana", 1.0 ]
      "Hawk", [ "Cherry", 1.1; "Pear", 1.4; "Orange", 1.2; "Apple", 1.1; "Banana", 1.0 ]
      "Turkey", [ "Cherry", 1.1; "Pear", 1.1; "Orange", 1.1; "Apple", 1.0; "Banana", 1.0 ]
      "Chicken", [ "Cherry", 1.1; "Pear", 1.1; "Orange", 1.1; "Apple", 1.0; "Banana", 1.0 ] ]

    let lookup = [ for x, y in listoflists -> x, y |> Map.ofList ] |> Map.ofList
    lookup.[bird].[fruit]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Martin521 mentioned, this is inefficient because you're rebuilding the maps each time. I would recommend using the `Map` constructor (instead of `Map.ofList`) to build the structure only once, outside of the getter:

```ml
let lookup =
    Map [
        "Eagle", Map [ "Cherry", 1.1; "Pear", 1.4; "Orange", 1.2; "Apple", 1.1; "Banana", 1.0 ]
        "Hawk", Map [ "Cherry", 1.1; "Pear", 1.4; "Orange", 1.2; "Apple", 1.1; "Banana", 1.0 ]
        "Turkey", Map [ "Cherry", 1.1; "Pear", 1.1; "Orange", 1.1; "Apple", 1.0; "Banana", 1.0 ]
        "Chicken", Map [ "Cherry", 1.1; "Pear", 1.1; "Orange", 1.1; "Apple", 1.0; "Banana", 1.0 ]
    ]

let getter bird fruit =
    lookup.[bird].[fruit]
```

Since this is intended to be a table of rows and columns, I would also consider using a [Deedle data frame](https://fslab.org/Deedle) instead of a map of maps.

Comment: Thank you, from my googling around yesterday for whatever reason every map example I found never mentioned a raw map constructor so I didn't know it was a thing.

My code is going to have a bunch of small tables that I'll need to pull from, but they're all really small like the 4x5 table in the question, and none of them needs to be transformed or changed ever, so I figured I'd just hard code them like this.

Comment: Yeah, the Map constructor isn't really called out the way it should be in the documentation, but it's very handy. Note that there's a function called `dict` that will do roughly the same thing, but creates an `IDictionary` instead of a map.

Answer (score 2):

I think the code is fine, but inefficient because the lists and maps are re-built in every call. This may be completely ok if the lists are not too large and if the function is not called that often.

If efficiency is a concern, you have to create the map outside of the function.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping to get ideas of more efficient ways of doing things from this post. Since I'm a noob programmer I'm sure I do a lot of things in clunky ways.

Answer (score 1):

I think a solution based on maps works perfectly fine in a simple case like this. But the Deedle library mentioned by Brian may be useful if your use case was more elaborate (and you also needed to load or transform the data). It has an efficient lookup of the kind you need built-in:

```
#r "nuget: Deedle"
open Deedle

let df = 
  frame
    [ "Eagle" => series [ "Cherry", 1.1; "Pear", 1.4; "Orange", 1.2; "Apple", 1.1; "Banana", 1.0 ]
      "Hawk" => series [ "Cherry", 1.1; "Pear", 1.4; "Orange", 1.2; "Apple", 1.1; "Banana", 1.0 ]
      "Turkey" => series [ "Cherry", 1.1; "Pear", 1.1; "Orange", 1.1; "Apple", 1.0; "Banana", 1.0 ]
      "Chicken" => series [ "Cherry", 1.1; "Pear", 1.1; "Orange", 1.1; "Apple", 1.0; "Banana", 1.0 ] ]

let getter bird fruit =
  df.[bird, fruit]

getter "Eagle" "Pear"
```